# Guidance on steps to debug this error message "Server Error in '/' Application"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm receiving the error message below on an existing asp.net application that otherwise works fine.  The problem occurs on any newly added page while old pages compile and preview fine.  The error message seems to be telling me exactly what the problem is...namely that it cannot load type "foo.web.webform2".  However for the life of me I can't figure out the solution.  I've scoured the internet for help to no avail.  Similar threads usually recommend something along the lines of rebuilding the application or deleting DLLs from the bin directory.  I've tried both and neither work.

I'd be very grateful if someone can tell me what to do next.  I'm equally interested in the answer as I am in hearing what steps you would go through in my situation to debug the problem.  In other words...I want to learn to fish.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Foo.Web.WebForm2'.
>      Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs"     Inherits="foo.Web.WebForm2" %>
>      Line 2:
>      Line 3:  
>      Source File: /WebForm2.aspx    Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4959; ASP.NET    Version:2.0.50727.4955

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you aren't getting build errors?  You would get that exception if your newly added page didn't compile so the previously compile dll is loaded which does not contain this new page.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  You pointed me in the right direction.  I was getting a couple of build errors but I was ignoring them because they were for pages unrelated to the one I was working on.  I excluded those pages from the project and voila, problem solved.  It wasn't a problem when I was making changes to older pages in the site (which I've previously compiled) but I see now why I can't just ignore build errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your source files or assemblies contain this class `Foo.Web.WebForm2`.

It seems like a class belonging to .aspx page and hence my first step would be to look into ASPX files containing something like `WebForm2.aspx`.

If its there, you might want to double check its namespace and where it's being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file WebForm2.aspx.cs

If it's missing, recreate it.
If it's misnamed, fix the name to match the one here in bold
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" **CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs"** Inherits="StorageByMail.Web.WebForm2" %>

If the class or namespace does not match, fix that.

If is something else, and you can't figure it out, ask for more help here.

Ben is correct, check for Build errors, (Actually look at the errors tab)